# Running Bottle + Python + Google App engine for the first time

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, bottle, google-cloud-platform

As the first step in creating a cloud based mobile app I chose to try out the Google Cloud trial period. So as per the instructions in https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.92011098.1535487967.1418404546, I installed the Google cloud SDK and Google App engine and tried out the following code snippet as mentioned in the instructions.

```
from bottle import Bottle

bottle = Bottle()

# Note: We don't need to call run() since our application is embedded within
# the App Engine WSGI application server.


@bottle.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello World!'


# Define an handler for 404 errors.
@bottle.error(404)
def error_404(error):
    """Return a custom 404 error."""
    return 'Sorry, nothing at this URL.'
```

As per instructions, I

1. Sign in to Google Cloud Platform using this command: `gcloud auth login`
2. Install the App Engine package for Python using this command: `gcloud components update gae-python`
3. Start a local server using this command: `dev_appserver.py appengine-try-python-bottle`

However, it generated the following logs (which I am not allowed to share here apparently because I haven't earned some points here) and localhost:8080 was blank. Can you please help me understand what am I missing here ?

Comment: Without seeing the logs it's quite hard to debug things.  Perhaps upload the logs to some site and show us the URL?  Also, did you also have the app.yaml and appengine_config.py as shown on that site?

Comment: Please share the logs.

Answer (score 1):

After putting bottle.py in the root directory and deploying it to GAE, the following code should work (template, static_file etc. will be probably useful for further development of the app so I am leaving them):

```
from bottle import route,run,template, view, request,response
from bottle import static_file
from bottle import Bottle
from bottle import default_app
from bottle import url

@route('/login')
def getHandlerLogin():
    return "<h1>Hello world</h1>"    

app=default_app()
```

Using bottle with GAE is not at all difficult, but in the long run it might be easier to use webapp2.

Answer (score 1):

Look here for an answer: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-bottle-skeleton

Those instructions worked perfectly for me.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for a starter, I think you shouldn't be using Bottle (or any other unsupported framework) on GAE. It's possible to use them, but it's not *simple*. It's what may be preventing your GAE app from starting. In all cases, we need more debug data!

Try using Webapp2. It was the first framework in python I ever used, but it was really simple to use (really, no more than Flask or Bottle). Here' the doc : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp

If you really want to use Bottle, being a WSGI-compliant microframework, it's apparently not so hard to set it up on GAE. Maybe use [this outdated tutorial](http://blog.rutwick.com/use-bottle-python-framework-with-google-app-engine) to try and make it work. There's [this github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-bottle-skeleton) that might also help you bootstrap your project.